# Problem with the Timer when using mouse double click

Tags: c#, timer, mouseclick-event

I need to Distinguish Between Clicks and Double-Clicks and I have used this solution with the timer [msdn.doubleclick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171543.aspx)

so I have a Timer function who looks something like this

```
private void doubleClickTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  milliseconds += 100;
  if (milliseconds >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime)
  {
    doubleClickTimer_.Stop();
    if (isDoubleClick)
      executeDoubleClick();
    else
      ExecuteSingleClick();
    isFirstClick = true;
    isDoubleClick = false;
   }
}
```

and this works ok, but in the ExecuteSingleClick I need the MouseEventArgs e, but all I have is the EventArgs e from the doubleClickTimer function, is there someway to get the MouseEventArgs from the doubleClickTimer so I can write like this:

```
ExecuteSingleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
   MouseButton button = e.button;
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start the timer, set its tag property to the `mouseeventargs` parameter (`e`). You can then use this in the `timer.tick` event callback (pass it to your execute(double)click functions).